# Standard practices in concurrent/parallel processing?

Tags: scala, haskell, heroku, concurrency, erlang

Simply, in what use case is it best to have many processes that get a msg off a queue and completes many tasks against that job sequentially or to have many tasks/processes getting that 1 msg off a queue and completing tasks against it.

I have one job coming to the queue. Clean my laundry.

I can do....

```
      [option A]
      Clean My Laundry -----> Wash it
                              then, Store Transaction
                              then, Tell ppl i'm washing
                              then, write a blog about it

      OR

     [option B]
     Clean My Laundry ------> Wash it
                      ------> Store Transaction
                      ------> Tell ppl i'm washing
                      ------> write a blog about it
```

The order of the tasks are irrelevant. They just all need to get done. I understand if they are dependent on each other, group them.

What's advantage or disadvantage of grouping or not grouping distributed processes?

thank you for any contribution.

Comment: What kind of advantage or disadvantage are you looking for?  Generally concurrency is done for performance or responsiveness reasons.

Comment: i just want to know why go with option a vs option b?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example shows parallelism rather than concurrency: parallelism is splitting up one task into subtasks and doing the subtasks at the same time; concurrency is lots of different things happening at the same time.

As you say, parallel processing is a good idea when your main task can be split into subtasks that are independent of each other.  The advantage is that the main task only takes as long as the longest subtask.

Simon Marlow's recent book on Parallel processing with Haskell is a good (thorough, very readable) introduction.